# Resize the HTML createTemplateFromFile

Tags: html, google-apps-script, modal-dialog, resize, showmodaldialog

I have a modal displaying a HTML form. Modal is set to standard width. but i need to resize the modal  to 900x900. After 2 days of study... not been able to do it.. please give me e solution (I'm a beginner)

```
//OPEN THE FORM retete IN MODAL DIALOG
function reteteModalDialog() {
var commesseAttive   = selArrashowFormInModalDialogyCommesse()
var elencoClienti    = selArrayClienti()
var elencoTipologie  = selArrayTipologie()
var elencoDimensioni = selArrayDimensioni()
var elencoVarianti   = selArrayVarianti()

  var form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("selCommessa");
    form.arrayOfNames     = commesseAttive; 
    form.arrayOfClienti   = elencoClienti;
    form.arrayOfTipologie = elencoTipologie;

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(form.evaluate(), "Retete");

}
```

just change the size of the html Modal

Comment: Hi, this is a CSS problem, and you didn't put any CSS. Please update your question, including all  the community needs for debugging. Please read  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: HtmlOuput has setHeight() and setWidth() methods

Comment: thanks, Cooper but the problem was how to use setHeight() and setWidth() methods. I have found the solution :  'SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(form.evaluate().setWidth(1200).setHeight(600), "Retete");'